# I need to redirect an directory but not an specific url request

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect the /home/ directory of my old site to the new site.

```
Redirect 301 "/" "http://www.new.com"
```

That would work perfect but it affects all users.

What I need is that the site won't redirect if an user requests an old Blog post.

```
/home/single-news.html?&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=8976&cHash=3010adecbf198a207f442a0e860429a9
```

After the directory home their is that request link. But I'am not able to figuring out how to not redirect that direct request.

Edit:
I would like that traffic to /home/ gets redirected to new website. But if someone request's that specific link /home/single-news.html?&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=8976&cHash=3010adecbf198a207f442a0e860429a9 it should not redirect

Thank's

Comment: Can you please share your current .htaccess file and how you've tried to solve your problem? I see you've clarified some of your question in other comments, can you also edit those into your original question?

Comment: The only thing I tryed was this 301 redirect. I don't really have an file right now. Since I'am looking arround how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear from your question of what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

If you want to redirect all requests that start with `home` and basically strip that from the new URL it would be something like:

```
RewriteRule "^/home/(.*)" "http://www.new.com/$1" [R=301]
```

Comment: You don't need the `L` flag here, since you are doing an _external redirection.